# Should the [work-environment] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, removal

It seems like questions that would fall under the [work-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment) tag are very likely to be migrated to The Workplace. Almost every question in the past two months under this tag have been closed and roughly half of them marked as off topic.

So should this tag be eliminated ?

---

**Moderator's Note**

For anyone working on the tag clean-up, please watch out for a few things:

If it's a question that should be closed, don't retag - flag or vote. If it's closed and can't be saved, flag for deletion. If it's a good question, try to make as many edits at the same time as possible (consider the title, body, any other tag changes, and answers).
Just don't flood the homepage with a bunch of minor edits to questions. It just buries new questions.

If you aren't sure if you can save a question, feel free to discuss it somewhere - in this question or in chat work. If an edit is going to be made, make it a good one.

Just generally reduce the number of edits to a single question as well as the number of questions you edit at a given moment in time. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure your question can really be answered with Workplace still in beta.  Looking up [Workplace's Area 51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/the-workplace) doesn't make it clear to me if it will make it out of the beta stage or not.

Comment: @GlenH7 not really relevant, Workplace's scope doesn't change Programmers' scope. But FYI, those are really damn good stats so far.

Comment: @BenBrocka - sorry I wasn't clear.  If Workplace becomes official, then we can create a formal path to migrate to Workplace from the close votes.  And at that point, the tag work-environment would definitely decrease in relevance / importance.  But since they're in Beta we can't formalize that path.  If Workplace wasn't there, then I would say we need the tag.

Answer (score 3):

No.

I think there are valid questions about work environment which are specific enough to programmers that they fit better here than on The Workplace.

Comment: Fully agree that there `are valid questions about work environment which are specific enough to programmers`. But do they benefit from the tag, would those questions miss it if it was gone? Is the tag confusing people that it's ok to ask general work environment questions? Notice that the OP says `almost every question in the past two months under this tag have been closed and roughly half of them marked as off topic` (and scanning through the tag that appears to be true).

Comment: My gut tells me that I agree with Philip. But when I look at the evidence myself, I find it to be one of those "in a perfect world" things.

Answer (score 3):

This tag needs to go. The general idea behind a tag is that it should be able to exist as the *only* tag on a question and still make sense. Therefore, with that logic, if the only tag I could conceivably add to a Programmers SE question is the [work-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment) tag, then the question is most likely off-topic.

With that said, I think Philip does make a good point that just because a question has a workplace element to it doesn't mean it's off topic here. Remember, we should be jealous of our communities!